# previous_post_link() next_post_link() arrow position

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

How can I make the arrow as part of the link please?

```
<?php next_post_link('%link &rarr;'); ?>
```

The output of above will be | `<a href="nextPostLink">NextPostTitle<a> arrow` |

Answer (score 5):

As the documentation for [`next_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) states, the *link* parameter is where the actual text of the **%link** placeholder goes. The *format*  parameter is the whole text, where **%link** is unpacked from the second *link* parameter. Solution:

```
next_post_link( '%link', '%title &rarr;' );
```

Expected output: `<a href="...">Title &rarr;</a>`

Something like this, on the other hand:

```
next_post_link( 'Over to %link now!', '-- %title --' );
```

...will result in: `Over to <a href="...">--- Title ---</a> now!`

See how these are unpacked?